# Best approach to aborting TCP transfer?

Tags: tcp

I'm dumping data from my server app to my client app in chunks (TCP/IP). At some point the client may wish to abort the transfer and make a new request to the server. The rapid approach to get this done is to kill the TCP connection so that any data already sent by the server and live on the network is dumped. The new connection will handle the new request/transfer so there is no delay in receiving old redundant data.

Is this an acceptable solution?

NB: I did consider breaking the chunks into smaller sizes separated by client ack messages but then you have the problem of fixing a chunk size....too small and too many acks (slowed transfer)....too big and there is still a residual delay in dumping redundant data.

Any ideas or standard design approaches that I should be aware of?
TIA

Comment: Either include some kind of abort command in the protocol, or just close the connection and reconnect. The important thing is that your client should probably discard any and all data already received. Equally important is that the server should not freak out when a client disconnects in the middle of the dump.

Comment: You should note that it might be quicker to just send an "abort" command followed by a new request for data, than to disconnect and reestablish the connection, followed by a request.

Comment: Thanks Joachim, could you elaborate on this "abort" command? I think that once the data has been sent by the server and is effectively in the pipeline the only way to prevent the client having to receive+decode+dump is to sever the connection completely.

Comment: The "pipeline" isn't actually that big, unless you count the buffers in the server, and even with that it won't be that much. You *do* have some sort of protocol between the client and server? Then you should know when the data ends, and worst case read until the end. As for the "abort" command, when the server receives it it should immediately stop sending data, and send some form of acknowledge of the abort, which the client will see and then know that it's not coming more old data.

Comment: I do have an 'abort' command which tells the server to stop sending but due to the buffers (in the TCP stack?) sent data cannot be recalled and has to be received by the client. In some cases this data can be large and causes a delay in the client (1-2 seconds) while this old data is purged. This is why I resorted to killing the connection which works fine (reconnection is very fast). I was just wondering if this approach is ok or frowned upon.

Comment: @kingrolo You need to figure out where the buffers are. If they're in the server software, but not the TCP stack, you can add a way to clear them. If they're in the TCP stack, you may want to think about whether they are bigger than they need to be. It could actually be that resetting the connection is actually the best method if aborting is infrequent and shrinking the buffers hurts server performance or throughput.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two TCP connection similar to FTP - one to send control request to the server & other transfers the actual data. If you wish to abort a transfer then just a request to abort it over control channel.

Comment: How does this solve my problem? I still have all the same issues with the data channel.

Comment: Associate each transfer with a unique request value & length of the data is about to send in the data channel. If the client wishes to abort a transfer it can send that over the control channel.

Answer (score 0):

**Send the data in chunks but don't acknowledge.** When the client wants to abort the transfer make it send a cancellation request to the server. The client now just throws away chunks (which are still arriving). Eventually, the server gets the cancellation request and stops sending data. If you want to you can make the server send an acknowledgement of cancellation.

This way you can have small chunks with minimal overhead. You could have 1KB chunks with a 4 or 8 byte chunk header containing the size of the chunk. That is an extremely small bandwidth and latency overhead.

Note, that a small chunk does not generally result in a small IP packet. TCP streams data. It does not care about your chunk size.

Comment: Without the acks the data is spewing from the server as previously and I still have the problem of dumping old data (this is the main issue). The server sends its chunks as fast as it can and rapidly fills any buffers.

Comment: @kingrolo TCP takes care of flow control and buffer sizing. The buffers will not become arbitrarily big. How big do you think they become? I believe the maximum is 64KB which is a TCP protocol limit. You can also configure the buffer size I believe.